# Getting the Name of a Column from the row and column indexes in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to know if it is possible to get the name of a column from the row and column indexes. i.e I want to have a function that would return the name of a column by passing the row index and the column index e.g let's say the name of my function is getColumnName. If I type getColumnName(1,8), I want it to return B8 for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex() method.

This accepts a numeric argument, e.g. 1 or 255, and will return the corresponding column letter, e.g. 'B' or 'IV' based on column 0 being 'A' and rows start from 1.

**EDIT**

If you only need this for setting cell values, then most cell manipulation functions such as

```
setCellValue()
```

have a corresponding method like

```
setCellValueByColumnAndRow()
```

that accept a row and column number rather than a cell address