# Find sequential column using PHPexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have to add (append) a row for every order users do in my website in a xls file. Actually i suppose PHPexcel is the best solution to do it.
Every column from A to K is reserved for shipping address. Column from L to O is reserved (blank). 
After those column i have to add one column with the id of each product user ordered. How can i do this without knowing every column letter? Is there a way to increment it for every item? This is my actual code:

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("ordini.xlsx");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;
//echo $row;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $orderid);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row, $orderid);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row, $array['nome']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$row, $array['cognome']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$row, $array['cellulare']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$row, $shippingmethod);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$row, "IT");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$row, $array['provincia']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$row, $array['citta']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$row, $array['indirizzo']." ".$array['civico']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.$row, $array['indirizzo']." ".$array['civico']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$row, "");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$row, "");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N'.$row, "");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O'.$row, "");
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('ordini.xlsx');
?>
```

Comment: See [Getting the Name of a Column from the row and column indexes in PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536964/getting-the-name-of-a-column-from-the-row-and-column-indexes-in-phpexcel).

Answer (score 0):

Using simple PHP string incrementing might help: set an initial variable (e.g. $column) to 'A', then just increment $column in a loop

```
$column = 'A';
for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) {
    echo $column++, PHP_EOL;
}
```

or

```
$column = 'A';
$lastColumn = 'IV';
$lastColumn++;
while ($column !== $lastColumn) {
    echo $column++, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Alternatively, the `setCellValueByColumnAndRow()` method uses simple row and column numbers